# How do I rewire this electrical panel?

Tags: electrical, grounding, electrical-panel

House was built in 50s or 60s, and there was a bundle of wires all grounded to the main ground lug.  I removed them and began to separate to disperse them along the ground bar, and three of them are hot. Also they are a mixture of white and bare wires.  Do I connect them to the ground bar?

Comment: Please do not tell us you were doing this will power on to these circuits?!?

Answer (score 3):

The neutrals are hot until they're connected to the neutral bus whenever the load is connected (switched on or whatever). **You have a very dangerous situation there whenever they're disconnected.** You should never disconnect neutrals or grounds unless the associated hot is disconnected or the breaker switched off.

**[More info and explanation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/122322/how-does-a-break-in-the-neutral-wire-enable-it-to-reach-the-full-line-voltage)**

In a main panel, ground and neutral are "bonded", and they share one or more bus bars. The neutrals and grounds for a particular branch circuit should never be installed together under a single screw. It is a code requirement that each neutral be terminated one per hole with no other wires. This prevents inadvertent and dangerous detachment of additional neutrals when working with a single screw.

UPDATE: [Here's a good discussion on 408.21](https://www.nachi.org/forum/f19/double-tapped-grounds-15895/), the section that covers this issue. My interpretation is that neutrals must be individually secured, but grounds can be doubled (or even tripled) when the hardware allows. Confusion often stems from the terms "grounded" and "grounding". The former refers to grounded neutrals, and the latter to (typically) bare ground conductors.

Comment: computer spazzing when I tryed to up vote I hope it worked. never pull  a neutral with the breaker on + from me most folks dont have a clue. but only 1 ground wire per screw 2 under screw is a code violation

Comment: @EdBeal, most modern panels and ground bars can legally and safely accept two or even three ground wires of the same size per hole. This typically only applies to #14-10.

Comment: Thanks for the correction,Speedy. That calls into question either 1) work I've seen from electrical contractors in the last 20 years, or 2) my own memory.

Comment: Sorry Speedy NEC 408.41 states each grounded conductor SHAL terminate in a individual terminal that is not used for another conductor. So there are no safe ways to put 2 grounded conductors under a screw.this has been code for many years.just checked an 02 code book still there 408.21 in 02 book

Comment: My previous home's panel was installed in 1998. Might code have changed since then with regard to shared ground/neutral connections? I recall them being installed under single screws in pairs.

Comment: I have been a licensed general journy since 79. I dont remember it being different but am sure it has been that way for close to 20 years. (when I moved to oregon and had to retest) I will try and to find old books I have them but just moved so I dont know where they are just now.

Comment: sinci I got ripped for the correct comment had to down vote since part of the answer was wrong and argued the point

Comment: It's not wrong anymore. What's the issue? (And retaliation voting is discouraged anyway.)

Comment: My interpretation of the doubled grounds is that it's approved as long as the panel is suited for it.

Comment: guys, when @SpeedyPetey referenced "ground wires" he was talking about *grounding conductors*, which indeed **can** be doubled up on the ground bar. The *grounded* conductors (neutrals) can never be.